# Batch won't work: compile one .txt file

Tags: windows, batch-file

This batch-command used to work, but now only creates an empty .txt file.
The aim was to create one .txt file out of the second lines of a big number of files.
Thanks for your help.

```
@echo off & setlocal
set "RootFolder=C:\"
set "FileNamePattern=*.txt"
set "OutFile=C:\VersionA.txt"

>"%FileList%" (
 for %%f in ("%RootFolder%\%FileNamePattern%") do (
    echo %%f
  )
)

>"%OutFile%" (
  for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%FileList%") do (
    for /f "skip=1 tokens=1* delims=:" %%b in ('findstr /n "^" "%%a"') do  (
  echo(%%c
)
  )
)
```

Comment: Whatever *used to work* may mean, you need to explain what the script is supposed to do and what it actually does. Only very few of us own a crystal ball...

Comment: you write to the root of c:\ ?? Also, you are giving a `*.txt` pattern, and your output file is a `.txt` file as well, that is not a good method.

Comment: The batch requires a previously defined variable `FileList` which seems no more the case.

Comment: You are missing an important line `5` in the script. It should begin with `Set "FileList=`, end with `"` and have a location in between for the list you were hoping to output. You cannot read `"%FileList%"` if you haven't defined that variable!

Comment: Thanks everyone! It works!

Comment: What works? adding the information I provided you in comment to your deleted answer, or one or more of the answers given below? Please clarify and mark the best solution as accepted if it is so; thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to `Set` a variable to `FileList`, you could just nest the `For` loops and not write to then read from a text file.

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "RootFolder=C:\"
Set "FileNamePattern=*.txt"
Set "OutFile=C:\VersionA.txt"

If Not Exist "%RootFolder%%FileNamePattern%" GoTo :EOF
(   For %%A In ("%RootFolder%%FileNamePattern%") Do (
        For /F "Skip=1 Tokens=1* Delims=:" %%B In ('FindStr /N "^" "%%A"'
        ) Do Echo=%%C))>"%OutFile%"
```

*I have removed the **`\`** from between `%RootFolder%%FileNamePattern%` because you have already have a trailing one on `%RootFolder%`. If in future you modify `%RootFolder%` please ensure it also has a trailing **`\`**.*

Answer (score 0):

`filelist` is undefined.

Set it appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear to me if the output should contain
file content from line 2 on or only line 2.

In case of the latter let findstr/find do the work - only one for.

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\04\26\SO50038130.cmd
@echo off & setlocal
set "RootFolder=C:\"
set "FileNamePattern=*.txt"
set "OutFile=C:\VersionA.txt"

Pushd  %RootFolder%
( for /f "tokens=2* delims=:" %%A in (
    'findstr /n "^" %FileNamePattern% ^|find ":2:"'
  ) do Echo:%%B
) >"%OutFile%"
PopD
```

Comment: My reading of their script is to output a single `OutFile` with the contents of each `.txt` file in `RootFolder`. _Similar to what `Copy`, `More` and `Type` can do_.

Comment: @Compo I read `The aim was to create one .txt file out of the second lines of a big number of files.` differently - so my attempt.

Comment: To reword that, their aim is to output to a single `OutFile` all content bar the first line of each `.txt` file in `RootFolder`. Similar to what `More +1` can do, for multiple files.